# create border around div and his children using wrapAll

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code not workin well.
I want to create border around div id="wrap_all" and his children
using warpAll().
Did Is it possible to use with `$("#wrap_all").wrapAll("<div></div>");`
If yes I don't know how to that.
I am allso don't know how to include `id="xxx"` inside `("<div id="xxx"></div>")`
order for manipulate the new div with id xxx to make

```
$(#'xxx')..css("border", "3px double red");
```

link for examle:http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/9TPtn/27/
Thanks.

code html:

```
<div  class="foo">a</div>
<div class="foo">b</div>
<div class="foo">c</div>
<div id="foo" class="foo">d</div>
 <div id ="wrap_all">
  <div class="foo">r</div>
  <div class="foo">f</div>
  <div class="foo">g</div>
 </div>
<div class="foo">h</div>
<span></span>​
```

link for examle.

jquery code:

```
var modWidth = 50;
$('#wrap_all').hover(function() {
    $(this).warpAll()
    $(this).css("background", "green");
    $(this).css("border", "3px double red");
    $(this).width(modWidth);


}, function() {
        $(this).css("background", "#cac");
         $(this).width(40);
    });
```

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions when they're solved. No accepted answers is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but the code you posted says

```
$(this).warpAll()
```

Instead of

```
$(this).wrapAll();
```

(Notice the corrected spelling of "wrap" and the added semicolon).